# json not displaying database values

Tags: php, json

My page has been uploaded to my uni server it is displaying the header but not the database values , bellow is the code im using (I put the code through a syntax checker and found no errors)

library page

```
  <?php

function getAllPictures() {
    //  include the login credentials
    include ("loginasdf.php") ; 
    //  connect to the database to get current state
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    if (!$conn) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }
    $sql = "select * from Pictures" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    //  convert to JSON
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    return json_encode($rows);
}  

?>
```

loginasdf

```
<h1>Display All Pictures</h1>

 <?php
// define the constants to access the database.

$servername = "***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "****";

?>
```

display pictures page

```
   <?php
    include("library2.php") ;
    $picturetxt = getAllPictures() ;
    $picturejson = json_decode($picturetxt) ;       
    //  now write out the details
            echo "name ".$picturejson -> hname."<br/>" ;
            echo "image " .$picturejson -> himage."<br/>" ;
    $cl = $picturejson;
    for ($i=0 ; $i<sizeof($cl) ; $i++) {
        echo "<a href=displaycontact2.php?id=" ;
        echo $cl[$i] -> id ;
        echo ">" ;
        echo $cl[$i] -> hname ;
        echo "</a><br/>" ;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try to narrow your search, does getAllPictures() return a valid json? What do you mean by `header` ?

Comment: @BadeaMihaiFlorin by header i just meant the,  <h1>Display All Pictures</h1>
sorry never realized that i hadn't put that in the question, ill edit it in

Answer (score 0):

I was accidentally using "dbname" on my loginasdf page and "database" for     $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database); on my library page